# How to aggregate multiple fields using Collectors in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a custom Object Itemized which has two fields amount and tax. I have an array of Itemized objects and I am looking to sum the two fields in the same stream. Below is how I am calculating the sum of both the fields.

```
double totalAmount = Arrays.stream(getCharges()).map(Itemized::getAmount).reduce(0.0, Double::sum));
double totalTax = Arrays.stream(getCharges()).map(Itemized::getTax).reduce(0.0, Double::sum));
```

Is there any way I don't have to parse the stream two times and can sum the two fields in one go ? I am not looking to sum totalTax and totalAmount but want their sum separately. I was looking at Collectors but was not able to find any example which would allow aggregating of multiple fields in one go.

Comment: One way could be *defining an entity which comprises of both the attributes* and their identities. Then as you stream `map` to that entity and `reduce` to find the sum of both.

Answer (score 4):

use a for loop ?

```
double taxSum = 0;
double amountSum = 0;
for (Itemized itemized : getCharges()) {
    taxSum += itemized.getTax();
    amountSum += itemized.getAmount();
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote, but he specified that he was looking for the fields summed by stream. Nevertheless, if streams are not absolutely required, this is the *best* solution.

Comment: @Avi There are less indents, less lines, less objects, less method calls, less blocks. Just less code, simpler and clearer.

Comment: Yes. Less confusion. But, he did specify a stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the teeing Collector, like so:

```
Arrays.stream(getCharges())                                // Get the charges as a stream
    .collect(Collectors                                    // collect
        .teeing(                                           // both of the following:
            Collectors.summingDouble(Itemized::getAmount), //     first, the amounts
            Collectors.summingDouble(Itemized::getTax),    //     second, the sums
            Map::entry                                     // and combine them as an Entry
        )
    );
```

This should give you a `Map.Entry<Double, Double>` with the sum of amounts as the key and the sum of tax as the value, which you can extract.

**Edit:**
Tested and compiled it - it works. Here we go:

> ItemizedTest.java

```
public class ItemizedTest
{
    static Itemized[] getCharges()
    {
        // sums should be first param = 30.6, second param = 75
        return new Itemized[] { new Itemized(10, 20), new Itemized(10.4,22), new Itemized(10.2, 33) };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map.Entry<Double, Double> sums = Arrays.stream(getCharges())
        .collect(Collectors
            .teeing(
                Collectors.summingDouble(Itemized::getAmount), 
                Collectors.summingDouble(Itemized::getTax),
                Map::entry
            )
        );
        System.out.println("sum of amounts: "+sums.getKey());
        System.out.println("sum of tax: "+sums.getValue());
    }
}
```

> Itemized.java

```
public final class Itemized
{
    final double amount;
    final double tax;

    public double getAmount()
    {
        return amount;
    }

    public double getTax()
    {
        return tax;
    }

    public Itemized(double amount, double tax)
    {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.tax = tax;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> sum of amounts: 30.6
>   sum of tax: 75.0

P.S.: `teeing` Collector is only available in Java 12+.

Comment: Worth mentioning Java-12 for `teeing` there. Given not a lot of people would have migrated to the latest JDKs either.

Comment: @Naman Good point. I had it on an earlier edit, I think, but I’ll put it back again.

Comment: I use Collectors method `reduce()`if it's more than two values, but then the accumulator function creates many short-living objects

Comment: Yeah - you can probably chain multiple teeing Collectors but it might start getting clunky after a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summing by field, you define a custom object to hold both field's sum values:

```
ItemizedValues {
    private double amount;
    private double tax;

    public static final ItemizedValues EMPTY = new ItemizedValues(0, 0);

    // Constructor - getter - setter
    public static ItemizedValues of(Itemized item) {
         return new ItemizedValues(amount, tax);
    }

    public static ItemizedValues sum(ItemizedValues a, ItemizedValues b) {
         // Sum the fields respectively
         // It's your choice to reuse the existing instances, modify the values or create a brand new one
    }
}

Arrays.stream(getCharges())
      .map(ItemizedValues::of)
      .reduce(ItemizedValues.EMPTY, ItemizedValues::sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

With a data structure that can allow one to accumulate both sums, you can reduce the stream to a single object.

This is using `double[]` to hold `totalAmount` at index 0 and `totalTax` at index 1 (other options include `SimpleEntry`, `Pair`):

```
double[] res = Arrays.stream(getCharges())
                .map(ch -> new double[] { ch.getAmount(), ch.getTax() })
                .reduce(new double[] { 0, 0 }, 
                        (a1, a2) -> new double[] { a1[0] + a2[0], a1[1] + a2[1] });

double totalAmount = res[0], 
       totalTax = res[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `Entry` but still you will end up in creating lot of objects, the best solution i would suggest is `for loop` answered by [NimChimpsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58229268/9959152)

```
Entry<Double, Double> entry = Arrays.stream(new Itemized[] {i1,i2})
          .map(it->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(it.getAmount(), it.getTax()))
          .reduce(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0.0,0.0),
                  (a,b)->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a.getKey()+b.getKey(),a.getValue()+b.getValue()));

    System.out.println("Amount : "+entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("Tax : "+entry.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, it's could be done by using your Itemized class as value holder.

```
Itemized result = Arrays.stream(getCharges())
    .reduce(new Itemized(), (acc, item) -> {
      acc.setAmount(acc.getAmount() + item.getAmount());
      acc.setTax(acc.getTax() + item.getTax());
      return acc;
    });
double totalAmount = result.getAmount();
double totalTax = result.getTax();
```